# django query set returns irrelevant result

Tags: python, django

in a django project I send a query set to database by ID but gets the answers but index. for example I need the query for ID 1 and 2 but gives me the result for index 1 and 2.. any hints?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

User query as Modelname.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2])

Comment: I exactly did this but the problem that I mentioned in the question occured.. is there any other way?